# Date is being changed in php

Tags: php, date, time

I have a text box for the user to submit a date. I have been testing it and when I submit `3 June 1851` PHP, for some reason changes it to `12/31/1969` instead of

> 06/03/1851

Is this a common problem? It works fine for dates in the 1900s but not the 1800s

EDIT:

Here is the PHP code:

```
$bday = strftime("%m/%d/%Y", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
$eyb = strftime("%Y", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
$em = strftime("%m", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
$ed = strftime("%d", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
$emd = strftime("%m/%d", strtotime($_POST['bday']));
$eya = $eyb + 110;
$edate = $emd . "/" . $eya;
```

Comment: could you give us the relevant part of your PHP code?

Comment: Show us the code you're using. `12/31/1969` means your date parser returned zero, which results in it outputting the start of Unix time, 1/1/1970 UTC.

Comment: @chresse I have added the code to the question

Comment: Either update to a 64-bit version of PHP, or start using DateTime objects

Comment: Note that only 6 people alive in the world today have a birthdate that falls outside the date range of a 32-bit unix timestamp

Comment: @MarkBaker I am aware of that. This is for ancestors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['bday']);
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted code, but I presume you're using [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime).

Per the docs:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.
>
> For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293 billion years in either direction.

Use the newer [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) functionality for better results.